# How to select the most recent 8 lines from a table for unique serial numbers in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I made automated test GUI's using labview that test our 8 channel devices.  Each time a test is completed, 8 rows are automatically added to a SQL Server table, and all of these 8 rows have the same Serial number recorded.  Every time a test is done, 8 rows are added regardless of whether this serial number has already been tested.  What I want to do is get the most recent data (always 8 Lines) for all the unique Serial Numbers.

So far I have only been able to do this for single line entry tests using the following code:

```
 SELECT TestIndex 
 FROM dbo.TROSA_101_InitialTestingLD_AsicLpTest_CH
 WHERE TestIndex IN (SELECT MAX(TestIndex) FROM dbo.TROSA_101_InitialTestingLD_AsicLpTest_CH GROUP BY SerialNumber)
```

Essentially I just want to remove the duplicate sets of 8 lines of data(each corresponding to one test) or in other words get the most recent 8 lines for each unique `SerialNumber` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely follow your business logic, but the requirement in the last sentence of your question is easy to come by using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY TestIndex DESC) rn
    FROM dbo.TROSA_101_InitialTestingLD_AsicLpTest_CH
) t
WHERE rn <= 8;
```

The above query would return the 8 most recent records for each serial number, with "recent" referring to the greatest `TestIndex` value.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly!  And yeah, the logic may not make the most sense lol.  We are in an R&D environment where I am responsible for many different tasks, so almost nothing is optimized!  Though I am curious what you mean if you have a different suggestion for how things should be done.  :)